# how to create a MODBUS in MATLAB simulink

Tags: matlab, tcp, simulink, modbus, scada

I want to create some command and response injection errors/attacks by using MOD-BUS communication protocol in MAT LAB. But i am unable to succeed to my goal from few months.

so,I tried via TCP/IP protocol communication protocol. I succeed some of my cyber attacks.But, some of response or command attacks are not fully satisfied as per my prerequisites. so i am decided to try once again Mod-bus in MAT-LAB. 
kindly help me, how can i create MOD-BUS blocks in MAT-LAB/simulation.

Thanks in advance

Yours sincerely,
sairam.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you [following solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44662-tcp-modbus-communication-with-yaskawa-controller) (TCP ModBus Communication With Yaskawa Controller) as a starting point. I used it myself successfully. 
"Using the tcpip command of the Instrumentation Control Toolbox messages are created and transmitted using the ModBus protocol. Various fucntions can be called to do read/write operations. "

Comment: without using any hardware components. can i get my result through only simulation in Matlab! (is there any possibilities)